# Docker : How to run grunt-open?

Tags: browser, docker

I have been using a grunt-open package for open my browser when i build my project. Recently I begin to use docker and this works perfectly, But the grunt-open task don't works anymore.

Exist some way to create a bridge between my docker and my local machine for opens my browser using grunt-open?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to open an external browser if you are running or building your project inside a docker container. The idea of using docker is to have all the tools you need inside the container.

You can use an gui less browser like PhantomJS and run grunt-open task inside the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "automatic" way - you would need to have some kind of listener on your local machine. So you can't really use grunt-open from the container but there are any number of ways you could have the grunt task in the container send a call to your local machine which could use `grunt-open` (or `npm-open` which it's a wrapper for, or `opn` which npm-open is a wrapper for) -- or a simple shell script.